# C++, web browser control: cannot change encoding/charset

Tags: c++, character-encoding, mshtml, iwebbrowser2, ihtmldocument2

There's a document I'm displaying in a web browser ActiveX control hosted in a C++ app. This document has a META tag that specifies **incorrect** charset, so the output is funny. I know the correct encoding and want to change it programmatically to fix that. But whatever I try, the encoding remains unchanged.

I alredy tried, in various combinations and flavors:

- `IHTMLDocument2::put_Charset` (after the document finished loading);
- changing the "charset" property of the "META" tag (using `IHTMLMetaElement`);
- deleting the "META" tag altogether (by setting its "outerHTML" to empty string);
- refreshing the control.

The control demonstrates remarkable persistence in preserving the incorrect encoding. What are my other options? I can't manipulate the source of the document being loaded.

Answer (score 1):

try to put the `designMode` property `"On"`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://p2p.wrox.com/visual-c/14280-change-page-encoding-webbrowser-activex-control.html), it should work if you call `IWebBrowser->Refresh()` after calling `IHTMLDocument2->put_charset()`.

Comment: Thanks, but Refresh doesn't help. If there is *no* meta tag, it works; if there's the *wrong* meta tag, it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what eventually worked:

In the handler of the "NavigateComplete2" browser event,

- the charset is modified using the charset property,
- *then* the META tag is thrown away by setting its outerHTML to empty string,
- and *then* the control is refreshed.

Modifying the order of these actions, or omitting a step, will render the entire operation void. MSHTML is picky.